# Publisher starts to receive constants back pressure

Tags: aeron

I start to use Aeron but faced the issue that over the time (exactly 3-4 hours after start) broadcast publishers receive constant backpressure.

My setup is the following:

1. Both publishers and subscribers are launched on the very same machine:
2. This is setup for the broadcast publishers:

```
    Publication: aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:55627|control-mode=dynamic|ssc=true -1991024233 6:0
    Publication: aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:35725|control-mode=dynamic|ssc=true -1991024232 7:0
    Publication: aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:40939|control-mode=dynamic|ssc=true -1991024231 8:0
    Publication: aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:57421|control-mode=dynamic|ssc=true -1991024230 9:0
    Publication: aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:60107|control-mode=dynamic|ssc=true -1991024229 10:0
```

2. This is setup for subscribers:

```
Subscription: aeron-spy:aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:35725|control-mode=dynamic|reliable=false 125:0
Subscription: aeron-spy:aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:40939|control-mode=dynamic|reliable=false 126:0
Subscription: aeron-spy:aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:55627|control-mode=dynamic|reliable=false 127:0
Subscription: aeron-spy:aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:57421|control-mode=dynamic|reliable=false 128:0
Subscription: aeron-spy:aeron:udp?control=0.0.0.0:60107|control-mode=dynamic|reliable=false 129:0
```

3. So basically I am using a spying connection.
4. In regards, to aeronmd configuration. I have tried the default one and with some config tweaks -> the same result.

So I wonder what could be the cause of this issue with backpressure. Hope somebody can help me (I have suspicious that a spy connection could cause this issue because there are no real subscribers, just a spy one)

UPD: same issue without aeron-spy

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, the issue was with that for tryClaim I used int32 while it return int64 so there were overflow that affected my conditional logic on commit